# How to synchronize current AVAudioPlayer time with Control Center?

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried the following:

```
func setInfo() {
    guard let splayer = player else { return }
    let simage: UIImage = mainImage2!
    let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
        return simage
    })
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playMusic))
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pauseMusic))
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(next(_:)))
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previous(_:)))
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: songText, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: splayer.duration, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1.0]
    timer1?.invalidate()
}
```

It works, but when I seek the track it doesn't update the time. Can you help me, please, so that it is constantly updated? Thank you!

Comment: I have a slider and by moving it, the song "jumps" at a different time (like the slider in the Apple's Music app), but in the Control Center the elapsed and the remaining time does not update to the new values, they just continue changing with the time before moving the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control center is completely independent of your app. All it is doing is counting seconds, based on the duration you configured it with at the outset. It is up to *you* to update the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter when your sound pauses or resumes or changes position, telling it what the current play position is. You are evidently not doing that.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing that "doesn't work". You still have not shown any of the relevant code.

Comment: `var songInfo = [String: Any]()` in the class, `songInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: songText, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork, MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: splayer.duration, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1.0]; 
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo
` initial declaration of the playing info; `songInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = aplayer.duration; MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo` when the slider's value is updated.

Comment: Any ideas, please?

Comment: What do you mean? You haven't done what I said. You need to be updating the now-playing-info's `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime`, but you evidently are not doing that.

Comment: I said in my answer "telling it what the current play position is".